# Using class method inside generic function

Tags: java, generics

**Situation:**

I want to write a generic function like the following:

```
public <T> void do(T para){
   para.something();
}
```

**Question:**
I want to give instances of two different classes to the do() function. Both classes are coming from an library, which has a bad design. Both classes have a something() method. But they are not implementing the same interface or extending the same superclass.

**My First though:**

I could write something like:

```
if(para instanceof A){
    ((A)para).something();
else if(para instanceof B){
    ((B)para).something();
}
```

I guess that would work, but I need to call something() more often and dont want to spam my code with this if/else. Has anyone a good clue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put the `something()` method in an interface implemented by your classes `A` and `B`, and bound the generic: `public <T extends YourInterface> ...`.

Comment: @AndyTurner both classes came from libraries

Comment: As I mentioned: A and B are coming out of an library. I don't want to change there code.

Comment: Do these classes contain many methods?

Comment: About 10 to 20. But additional to that about 100 coming from superclasses and interfaces.

Comment: Then wrap the `A` and `B` classes in something that implements your own interface, and have those wrappers call the `something()` methods.

Comment: I'm wondering if `@FunctionalInterface` could be of use here - if you're only interested in one method in both, you could have the `do` method accept that that interface and when using the method, pass a method reference (e.g. `do(someObject::something)`. Anyone see an obvious downside here?

Comment: Don't understand to 100% what you mean. Can you provide a better example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend and interface approach:

```
public interface ISomething {
    public void mySomething();
}

public ExtendA extends A implements ISomething {
    public void mySomething() { something(); }
}

public ExtendB extends B implements ISomething {
    public void mySomething() { something(); }
}
```

or like mentioned in the comments with a wrapper:

```
public interface ISomething {
    public void something();
}

public WrapperA implements ISomething {
    private A a;

    WrapperA(A a) {
       this.a = a;
    }

    public void something() {
        return a.something();
    }
}

public WrapperB implements ISomething {
    private B b;

    WrapperB(B b) {
       this.b = b;
    }

    public void something() {
        return b.something();
    }
}

A instanceOfA = ...;
ISomething some = new Wrapper(instanceOfA);
some.something();
```

another approach would be reflection, which is not as fast as the other approaches I suppose:

```
A instanceOfA = ...;
methodName = "something";
Method somethingMethod = instanceOfA.getClass().getMethod(methodName);
somethingMethod.invoke(instanceOfA);
```

Comment: is it a good idea to extend? or it's better to do wrapper? i think it's better to add more explanation.

Comment: @Kevin Wallis Does look good. The problem is, that I am not creating the instances myself. They are return values from the library.

Comment: I thought about reflection, and it was no option for me. I should have mentioned that in the question, sorry.

Comment: Okay :) (the answer shows different ways , maybe someone else could use them)

Answer (score 3):

Since you can't change the existing library you could make your own interface:

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    void doSomething();
}

public class C extends A implements SomeInterface {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        this.something();
    }
}

public class D extends B implements SomeInterface {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        this.something();
    }
}

public <T extends SomeInterface> void do(T param) {
    param.doSomething();
}
```

As mentioned in the comments it might be better to not extend A and B, but keep instance variables of A and B in your wrapper class:

```
public class C implements SomeInterface {

        private A a;
        public C(A a) { this.a = a; }

        @Override
        public void doSomething() {
            a.something();
        }
}
```

Also, with Java 8 this might be an easier solution:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface SomeInterface {
        void doSomething();
}
public <T extends SomeInterface> void do(T param) {
    param.doSomething();
}
do(p -> a.something());
```

Comment: you were faster ;)

Comment: @Bene
Does look good. The problem is, that I am not creating the instances myself. They are return values from the library.

Comment: Why is a Functional Interface better? I still need to create the Wrapper classes and still need a generic function. I see no advantage.

Comment: You don't need the wrapper classes anymore. Just call the generic method with a lambda expression. You can also make the method non-generic and use SomeInterface as the type of param. No time to try it out, but should work both ways.

Comment: the extends bound is not necessary.